# remove duplicated rows in Pandas df that don't meet a condition

Tags: pandas, duplicates

Reformulating an unclear question I previously asked.
I have a df like the following.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':  ['Bill','Bill','Bill','John','John','Greg','Greg','Andy','Tom','Jeff'],
        'age_matches': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        'height_matches': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'weight_matches' :[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        'Score': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Name','age_matches','height_matches','weight_matches','Score'])


Name    age_matches height_matches  weight_matches  Score
Bill           1          0              0            1
Bill           0          0              1            1
Bill           0          1              0            1
John           0          1              1            2
John           1          1              0            2
Greg           0          0              1            1
Greg           0          1              0            1
Andy           0          1              0            1
Tom            1          1              1            3
Jeff           0          1              0            1
```

I'm matching some observations along a series of features (age, height, weight). 1 means there's a match, 0 no match. `Score` is the sum of all matches by observation.
`Age_matches` takes precedence on other matches. If, within a group (same name), I have a case where (`age_matches` == 1), then I do NOT want to keep the other records. On the other hand, 
if within a group there is no instance of `age_matches` == 1, then I can keep all the records. The resulting df should look like this:

```
Name    age_matches height_matches  weight_matches  Score
Bill           1          0              0            1
John           1          1              0            2
Greg           0          0              1            1
Greg           0          1              0            1
Andy           0          1              0            1
Tom            1          1              1            3
Jeff           0          1              0            1
```

In the 'Bill' group, I had an observation where `age_matches` == 1, so I can drop the other records. Same in the 'John' group. All the rest was kept.
Hope this is clear enough. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I will do

```
df=df[df.groupby('Name').age_matches.transform('max')==df.age_matches]
   Name  age_matches  height_matches  weight_matches  Score
0  Bill            1               0               0      1
4  John            1               1               0      2
5  Greg            0               0               1      1
6  Greg            0               1               0      1
7  Andy            0               1               0      1
8   Tom            1               1               1      3
9  Jeff            0               1               0      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
m = df.age_matches.eq(1)
m1 = m.groupby(df.Name).transform('sum').eq(0)

df_final = df[m | m1]

Out[250]:
   Name  age_matches  height_matches  weight_matches  Score
0  Bill            1               0               0      1
4  John            1               1               0      2
5  Greg            0               0               1      1
6  Greg            0               1               0      1
7  Andy            0               1               0      1
8   Tom            1               1               1      3
9  Jeff            0               1               0      1
```